# Building a Document-based Question Answering Assistant with OpenAI's LLM - Cost-effective Strategies for Testing

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I'm working on a project that involves building a question-answering assistant using OpenAI's large language model (LLM). My goal is to make this assistant capable of answering questions related to a collection of informative documents.

I have already built this assistant using python + langchain + openai and it working as expected.

I understand that utilizing the OPENAI_API_KEY is necessary to access the model, but it comes with associated costs. As I'm in the testing and development phase, I'd like to explore cost-effective strategies to minimize expenses during this stage.

Here are my specific concerns:

**Free Tier Limitations**: I'm aware of the OpenAI free tier, but it has limitations in terms of usage and may not be sufficient for extensive testing. What are the best practices for staying within these limits while still getting meaningful results during development?

**Sample Data Usage**: Are there ways to optimize the usage of sample data provided by OpenAI for testing? How can I make the most of this data without incurring additional charges?

**Alternative Development Environments**: Are there alternative development environments or strategies that allow me to test and refine my question-answering assistant without relying heavily on the API and incurring costs?

I appreciate any insights or tips on how to manage costs effectively during the initial development and testing phase of my project. My ultimate aim is to create a valuable assistant without overspending in the early stages.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can use Private GPT on you local instance, but you need to know all details how to make it work locally. Secondly testing with local and production model will 100% lead to different results are you OK with it.

Comment: Well, we did explore that a bit. That seems to require the LLM model also to be downloaded and since the model size is too large, it requires high end machines for development. Also the unit testing times also seemed more because of slow responses. Because of this, we did not explore it further.